# nginx error.log Not a directory

Tags: bash, nginx, digital-ocean

I am trying to a access the error log of my Digital Ocean Django droplet.
When I try to charge directory from the / to /var/log/nginx/error.log I get `-bash: cd: error.log: Not a directory`
The file is there I can access it manually through Cyberduck. I am trying to figure what's wrong with my smtp contact form and can't if I can't get access to the error.log file. Any help would be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change directory to a file. You would cd to the folder that holds the file first:

```
cd /var/log/nginx
```

From there you can manipulate with just error.log:

```
vim error.log # edit/view file
tail error.log # view last lines of file
cat error.log # output contents of file to screen
```

You can however do any of those commands with the full path as well (and do it from anywhere):

```
vim /var/log/nginx/error.log # edit/view file
tail /var/log/nginx/error.log # view last lines of file
cat /var/log/nginx/error.log # output contents of file to screen
```

Comment: Is there a way to see the errors as they happen in the terminal that is connected to the server? I'm learning. haha Thanks for your help

Comment: With `tail`, you can use the `-f` flag to *follow* a file as it grows.

Reference: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=tail+-f

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error message because error.log is not a directory, it's a text file. If you want to read it, you can probably use a text editor like nano or vim or whatever text editor is included in your DO droplet.